# Do we have to submit the WordPress categories in search results?

Tags: duplicate-content, categories

I have submitted WordPress categories in search results and now I am seeing the "HTML improvements" area in webmaster tools suggest that single page having multiple tags is perceived as different pages by Google.

Should I delete the categories sitemap?

Comment: Can you perhaps add a screen shot of the errors from Search Console, it's not clear from your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what "single pgae having multiple tags" means.    Please edit your question to clarify.   The screenshot would help.